# Have `Power mode (on battery)` revert to a default upon wake-up?

Tags: windows-10, performance, power-management

I just learned that on Windows 10, I can double-click the battery icon on the lower right corner of the desktop and access a control for the CPU performance when running off the battery.  I will only need to set this to allow peak clock rates when working on certain things.  I know for a fact, however, that I will forget to dial it back down when I'm done.  Is there a way to have it always take on a default setting (say, one notch away from maximum) whenever it powers up, wakes up from sleep/hibernation, and whenever I log in?

Comment: I read through your comments and I will delete my answer as it is not helping you. No problems.

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't mean to create offense.  Was wondering whether I overreacted.

Comment: No offense taken. It simply appeared that my thinking was not what you desired.

Comment: Glad to hear (that I didn't offend).  Thanks for letting me know.